# do we have akismet api to be used on html pages?

Tags: asp.net, html

for the purpose of preventing spam in my application, i wanted to try Akismet plugin. But the page is a html page in the asp.net application. do we have any akismet api for html pages. Please let me know..

PS: i need to retain it as a html page, and not change it to an aspx page.

Thanks in advance,
Geetha

Comment: What a spammer is going to do with a static HTML page, if there's nothing to submit somewhere?

Comment: no..it s a 'contact us' page..that is a html(content) page in the web application..so it s basically a mailing functionality. wanted to know if akismet api s are avl for using in the html page..

Comment: You need a server side handler to take the submitted form data and email it. Any spam prevention needs to be done in that handler. You can't do it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Akismet C# API for the .Net Framework 1.1 and 2.0](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/2006/04/18/akismet-anti-spam-library-for-the-dotnet-framework/).

This is a little Microsoft .Net class which allows you to use the powerful Akismet comment spam protection in your .Net wiki/blog/website/software.

Edit: You can try [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/resources.html) as well.

Comment: thanks for this link..i did find this link when i googled.. but not sure, if i can use this on my html page..

Comment: wel.. how long would it take you to rename html file to asp.net

Comment: then try recaptcha, not sure whether it has js api or not. Why are you protecting the form?? you can just use a basic captcha (question) to protect spam.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..used this link that was very helpful http://www.captcha.cc/